# Is a += b different than a = a+b?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I think because pandas return a view of a dataframe when you manipulate a column out of your DataFrame it will affect on your original DataFrame but when i run first code it changes the column as it should but in second one it wont and i cant explain why ?! can anyone explain this to me ?

```
costs = df['Cost']
costs += 2
```

```
costs = df['Cost']
costs = costs + 2
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, they are different.